# sql count where result is greater than certain number

Tags: mysql, sql, count

The following query will sum the goals for each match:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Goals)
FROM `Team Match Table`
WHERE Match_Id IN (SELECT ID FROM Match Table
  WHERE HomeTeam_ID = (SELECT ID FROM `Team Table` WHERE `Team Name` = 'Aberdeen')
  OR AwayTeam_ID = (SELECT ID FROM `Team Table` WHERE `Team Name` = 'Aberdeen'))
GROUP by Match_Id
```

Is it possible to count how many of the results are greater than a certain number?

Comment: You should put some effort into formatting your query.  In addition, sample data and desired results would help communicate what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM()` on the condition to give you the count:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Goals) total_goals,
    SUM(Goals > 5) over_5_goals_count
FROM `Team Match Table`
WHERE Match_Id IN (SELECT ID FROM Match Table
  WHERE HomeTeam_ID = (SELECT ID FROM `Team Table` WHERE `Team Name` = 'Aberdeen')
  OR AwayTeam_ID = (SELECT ID FROM `Team Table` WHERE `Team Name` = 'Aberdeen'))
GROUP by Match_Id
```

This works (with mysql only), because mysql treats `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`, so summing the result of a condition gives you the count of the number of times it was true.

I chose `> 5` as the condition. You can use whatever threshold you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is the table name 'Team Match Table is correct' ? As sql will not allow you to create a table name with space .

Query it in a perfect format .

select sum(goals) from team_match_table where match_is in (select id from match table where hometeam_id in (select id from team_table where team_name='Aberdeen'or awayteam_id in (select id from team_table where team_name='Aberdeen'))) ;

Rather than giving a condition you can use a specific values in a table to pull out perfect result .

Just list out the tables you have , its common column as well

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
SELECT Match_id, SUM(`Goals`)
FROM `Team Match Table`
WHERE `Match_Id` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `Match Table`
                 WHERE `HomeTeam_ID` = (SELECT `ID` FROM `Team Table`
                                        WHERE `Team Name` = 'Aberdeen')
                    OR `AwayTeam_ID` = (SELECT `ID` FROM `Team Table`
                                        WHERE `Team Name` = 'Aberdeen'))
GROUP by `Match_Id`
HAVING SUM('Goals') >= DesiredNumber --Change DesiredNumber to a numeric value you wish to filter by
```

I've put the Match_id in the returned columns so that you can tell which matches have the number of goals you want to return. It will also tell you the number of goals in that match